# Dynamo - Add item only if its value is same or record does not exists

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

Recently, I have started working with Dynamo. And came across a scenario where I want to add entry in it only when it already does not exists or when its attribute value is same.
For e.g.

```
insert {'h': 1, 'r': 2, 'attr': {'attr': 'value1'}} should succeed, as record not present already
insert {'h': 1, 'r': 2, 'attr': {'attr': 'value1'}} should succeed, as same record exist with same information
insert {'h': 1, 'r': 2, 'attr': {'attr': 'value2'}} should fail, as attribute value is different
```

As I want to do it in single instruction to maintain atomicity, how can I achieve this using expected_value condition in Dynamo?

Any help appreciable

Comment: What is your HASH key in this scenario ? if 'h' is your hash key how do you expect to have duplicate items on the same primary key ??

Comment: As record can be identified by combination of 'h' and 'r' that is hash and range key. I can have 2 items for same hkey but with different rkey

Comment: but you insert same 'h' and 'r' key as well. still duplicate. If you choose another 'r' then how do you expect dynamo to check if attributes are same?? (Since its totally another item). Its like inserting an apple and expecting it to b checked against an orange.